# How do I get 'tr's ID with checkbox checked in code behind using C#

Tags: c#, html, checkbox

I got some problem and let me spend some time on testing.

I have a `ListView` , and a `checkbox` inside this, and a button outside.

When I `click button` , will show the rows `Tr ID` that rows `checkbox checked`.

but it always show `ctrl2` instead of ID.

This is my code:

```html
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <table cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" width="125">Man
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col" width="50">Type
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col" width="400">Reason
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col" width="125">date
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col" width="100">cheack
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col" width="125">remark
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                            </table>
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr id="<%#Eval("ID").ToString()%>" runat="server">
                                <td scope="col" >
                                    <%#Eval("UserID").ToString()%>
                                </td>
                                <td scope="col">
                                    <%#Eval("Purpose").ToString() %>
                                </td>
                                <td scope="col">
                                    <%#Eval("Reason").ToString() %>
                                </td>
                                <td scope="col">
                                    <%#dateSession(Convert.ToDateTime( Eval("startTime"))) %>
                                </td>
                                <td scope="col">
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked="True" />
                                </td>
                                <td scope="col">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
```

This is my code behind

```
protected void Btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem row in this.ListView1.Items)
    {
        CheckBox stylistcheck = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");

        if (stylistcheck.Checked == true)
        {
            Response.Write(row.ID);
            // Always get wrong ID , like 'ctrl3' not real rows Tr ID
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing this `<tr id="<%#Eval("ID").ToString()%>" runat="server">` will throw an error, AFAIR. If your goal is to get the `ID` for each row that represents your data then you can just add a literal control, hide it, and get it's value in code-behind. Something like:

```
<tr runat="server">
    <td scope="col" >
        <%# Eval("UserID").ToString()%>
        <asp:Literal ID="idLiteral" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID").ToString()%>' Visible="false" ></asp:Literal>
    </td>
    ...rest of your code goes here...
</tr>
```

In code-behind, inside your `if (stylistcheck.Checked == true)` do a `Response.Write(((Literal)row.FindControl("idLiteral")).Text);` like so:

```
if (stylistcheck.Checked == true)
{
    Response.Write(((Literal)row.FindControl("idLiteral")).Text);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckBox1.Checked = true;
```

It may help you.

OR

```
CheckBox chkDelete = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("CheckBox1");
if(chkDelete.Checked)
{
    string yourID = item.DataItem["id"].ToString();
    itemsToDelete.Add(yourID);
}
```

OR

```
 if (CheckBox1.Checked==true)
    {

    }
```

This may  also work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 yourListView.DataSource = GetCourses();
 yourListView.DataBind();

 var checkBox = yourListView.Controls.Cast<Control>).First().FindControl("yourID")
```

or

```
if (item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem){

CheckBox final = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("yourID");
if (final.Checked)  {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering are you sure you can run this code ?

```
<tr id="<%#Eval("ID").ToString()%>" runat="server">
```

I tried your code and run it will encounter error on this line...

Because with " you will get error server tag is not well formed.

If i use this ' the error will be :
The ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute in the tag and a simple value.

I write the code which will retrieve ID might help you...

.aspx

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" >
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="tbllol" runat="server" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" width="100">cheack
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col" width="125">remark
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td scope="col">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox" runat="server" Checked="true" />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td scope="col">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemarks" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>

    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btn_Click" />
```

.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Variable
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID");

        // Loop & Add ID
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) dt.Rows.Add("myIDIi" + i);

        ListView1.DataSource = dt;
        ListView1.DataBind();



    }
}

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Variable
    string value = string.Empty;

    // Loop
    foreach (ListViewItem row in ListView1.Items)
    {
        // Find Control
        CheckBox chkbox = row.FindControl("chkBox") as CheckBox;
        Label lblID = row.FindControl("lblID") as Label;

        // Check & Check Then Set to Value
        if (chkbox != null && chkbox.Checked)
            if (lblID != null) value += lblID.Text.Trim() + "<br />";
    }

    Response.Write(value);
}
```